# Pipeline in loop when using maven-release-plugin

Tags: git, maven-release-plugin, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a pipeline setup to do a automated release when I commit to a specific branch. The problem is that maven-release-plugin that I use commit its changes to the same repository and branch. This triggers the same pipeline and creates a loop.

How to exclude sertain commits for a specific branch?

```
- step:
    name: TEST01 - Automatic build and test
    caches:
      - maven
    script:
      # Here I would like to add a check to stop if some criteria is met like commitmessage==[maven-release-plugin] or something similar
      - mvn release:clean release:prepare --batch-mode -f ggw- core/pom.xml -s ggw-core/external/settings-test01.xml
      - mvn release:perform -f ggw-core/pom.xml -s ggw-core/external/settings-test01.xml -X -e
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the answer from the Atlassian team a quick and to the point answer! :)

Just add the flag -DscmCommentPrefix="[skip ci]" as shown below and 
maven-release-plugin will ignore the additional commits.

```
- mvn -batch-mode release:prepare -DscmCommentPrefix="[skip ci]"
```

For a more complete answer follow the link.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-can-I-configure-my-pipeline-to-control-versioning/qaq-p/553721#M91377

Comment: Added the same in Jenkinsfile.. Seems to be not working..

Working on CI with  Jenkins+GitLab

Comment: This is not ment for buildtools like jenkins. It is as a plugin for the pom in maven.